# How to manipulate numbers in a file"?

Tags: command-line

I attached both picture and *.txt file https://1drv.ms/t/s!Aoomvi55MLAQh1jODfUxa-xurns_   of a sample work file. In this file Reactions which only start with "r1f", "r2f", "r3f"......and so on. And for each reaction the reaction rates is situated couple of lines later with a "+" sign. 
  I want to change the first And 3rd numbers in reaction rates with +/-75%. So there will be 4 changed values for each reaction. 
So if in the Prob01.txt file there are 6 reactions then I want to have 6*4=24 txt files each have only one change in the reaction rates. 
That means only for first reaction i want four Prob01.txt files comprised of 4 changes in the reaction 1.

Comment: OneDrive link doesn't work. Don't post pictures, post a snippet of the input and a snippet of the output as *text*.

Comment: Have you read up on the usual command line tools to solve this, e.g. `awk`?

Comment: So there is only one changed rate per combination? i.e. (value1+75%, value2, value3) (value1-75%, value2, value3) (value1, value2, value3+75%) (value1, value2, value3-75%). Is that what you mean?

Comment: your file link is broken....

Comment: It's still very unclear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this .... definitely a sledgehammer.

Invoke it as `thisScript Prob01.txt 0.75 0.25` to apply combinations of +/-75% change on the 1st and +/-25% on the 3rd values on each reaction and write them to separate files

```
#!/bin/bash
#takes $inputFile $pct1 $pct3
#note $pct is the multiplier expressed as a decimal

#global variables
#$w       : the line number and original figures, space separated
#$newFile : the new file name
#$o       : the original figures in the original format
#$n       : the new figures in the correct format
inputFile=$1
#strip the suffix (.txt) from the inputFile name 
outFile=${inputFile%.*}
pct1=$2
pct3=$3

function domath {
    # takes $value $multiplier
    local m=$(echo 1+$2 | bc -l)
    local theanswer=$(echo $1 $m | awk '{printf "%7.6E\n" , $1*$2}' | sed -E -e 's/[Ee]\+*/E/g' -e 's/^([^-])/+\1/g')
    echo $theanswer
}

function makechange {
    #takes $reaction $case
    #compose new file name
    newFile=${outFile}_$1_$(printf "%02g" $2).txt
    #make a copy
    cp $inputFile $newFile
    #change the appropriate line
    sed -i "${w[0]}s/$o/$n/" $newFile
}

#get all the reaction names
grep -Po "^r[0-9]+f(?=:)" Prob01.txt > stepA

#get all the figures and their line numbers in case duplicates occur
grep -Pon "^\+[^\!]*" Prob01.txt > stepB

for ((i=1; i<=$(cat stepA | wc -l); i++)); do
    reaction=$(sed "${i}q;d" stepA)
    figures=$(sed "${i}q;d" stepB | sed 's/:/ /g')
    w=($figures)
    #retrieve the old string
    o=$(echo $figures | grep -Po "(?<= ).*")
    #compose the new string for each of the 4 cases
    for ((j=1; j<=4; j++)); do
        case $j in
            1)
                n=$(echo "$(domath ${w[1]} $pct1)  ${w[2]}  ${w[3]}")
                ;;
            2)
                n=$(echo "$(domath ${w[1]} -$pct1)  ${w[2]}  ${w[3]}")
                ;;
            3)
                n=$(echo "${w[1]}  ${w[2]}  $(domath ${w[3]}  $pct3)")
                ;;
            4)
                n=$(echo "${w[1]}  ${w[2]}  $(domath ${w[3]}  -$pct3)")
                ;;
        esac
        #make the changes
        makechange $reaction $j
    done

done
#clean up
rm step{A..B}
```

Comment: I am sorry. I edited my Question.

Comment: I don't want to change reaction rates in stepOne, I want to change in Prob01.txt. And want to create a version of txt files for each changes.

Comment: It also gives an error like "$inFile: ambiguous redirect"

Comment: Check the 'usage` comment on the 2nd line. From the directory with the `stepOne` (the input file) invoke the scripts as `thisScript stepOne 1.5` to generate an individual file where each reaction rate  is amended by the multiplier (1.5 in this case). Works fine on my machine. Your Prob01.txt will be written to stepOne.1.5.01 (stepOne file with a multiplier of 1.5 and the rate for reaction 01 amended. The file stepOne.1.5.02 is the rate amended for reaction 01 etc etc

Comment: Thanks for your time and effort. 
I don't want my Prob01.txt to be written in stepOne files. I want the output *.txt file just like Prob01.txt with changed reaction rates.

Comment: Thank you so much. You just saved my ass. I am a chemistry guy so don't know much about scripting. 
Two quick questions : If original file name is Prob.txt. How can I get the output like Prob01.txt, Prob02.txt, Prob03.txt..... and so on. 
And where should I change for the multiplier? I mean where should I put 0.75 for 75% change?

Comment: If you read the post carefully you will see that the multiplier goes on the command line when you invoke the script. On the numbering are you saying you just need Prob01 to Prob24 for the filenames? If you let me know I will edit. If you do this often then practice your scripting.....

Comment: I am sorry i don't know what does it mean by invoking a script. I mean, shouldn't I put somewhere the percentage (e.g 75%)? Can you give an example for 75%?   For reaction r1f there are 4 combination of changes. So I want Prob_r1f_01.txt, Prob_r1f_02.txt, Prob_r1f_03.txt and Prob_r1f_04.txt for r1f. So for one reaction I need 4 txt files. And so for r2f I need Prob_r2f_01.txt, Prob_r2f_02.txt, Prob_r2f_03.txt and Prob_r2f_04.txt........
And The output files should always be with *.txt extension. And should be saved in a certain directory.
I am bragging as one of our programmers got sick.

Comment: Hello again. I wanted to change the 3rd column with different percentage. That's why I made another function like domath. But I am getting an error message like "(standard_in) 2: syntax error". 
This are my changes :
`pxt=$3
.
function E_factor_manipulation {
    # $1 $3 
    # value multiplier
    local m=$(echo 1+$3 | bc -l)
    local theanswer=$(echo $1 $m | awk '{printf "%7.6E\n" , $1*$3}' | sed -E -e 's/[Ee]\+*/E/g' -e 's/^([^-])/+\1/g')
    echo $theanswer
}
New_string=$(echo "${w[1]}  ${w[2]}  $(E_factor_manipulation ${w[3]}   $pxt)")`

Comment: May be better to post the full script and ask for help in debug... maybe even close this post with accepting the answer if it helped? Seems that what you want to is very easy with a second pct on the command line applied to the 3rd field. But this post is getting messy ....better start afresh

Comment: Code updated so that it you use it in the form `thisScript Prob01.txt pct1 pct3` where the two different percentages are applied to the 1st and 3rd numbers accordingly

Answer (score 0):

here is a funky version in bash

```
#!/bin/bash

r=""
res=""
while read line; do
if [[ "$line" =~ ^(r[0-9]+f:[^ \t]+)[[:space:]]+\!+.+$ ]]; then
  r="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
if [[ "$line" =~ ^(\+[0-9]+\..+[0-9])[[:space:]]+\!+.+$ ]]; then
  res="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
if [[ -n "$r" ]] && [[ -n "$res" ]]; then
  echo -e "$r\t\t$res"
  r=""
  res=""
fi
done < <(grep -E "^r[0-9]+f:|^\+[0-9]+\." /path/to/yourfile)
```

this will insert 2 "tab" between your fields, don't know if it's what you need.
And my grep is a bit "wide", you can adjust that if you want.

result:

```
:/tmp$ bash script 
r1f:O2+2PD=>2O-PD       +7.000000E-02  +0.000000E00  +0.000000E00
r2f:C3H6+2PD=>C3H6-PD       +9.800000E-01  +0.000000E00  +0.000000E00
r3f:C3H6+O-PD+PD=>C3H5-PD+OH-PD     +2.747319E-01  +0.000000E00  +0.000000E00
r4f:H2+2PD=>2H-PD       +4.600000E-02  +0.000000E00  +0.000000E00
r5f:H2O+PD=>H2O-PD      +2.492452E-01  +0.000000E00  +0.000000E00
r6f:CO2+PD=>CO2-PD      +5.000000E-03  +0.000000E00  +0.000000E00
```

For your +75% thing, it makes things a bit more complicated as bash can't handle real numbers. So, here is a dirty solution with bash and awk.

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line; do
if [[ "$line" =~ ^(r[0-9]+f:[^ \t]+)[[:space:]]+\!+.+$ ]]; then
  r="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
if [[ "$line" =~ ^(\+[0-9\.Ee-]+)[[:space:]]+(\+[0-9\.Ee-]+)[[:space:]]+(\+[0-9\.Ee-]+)[[:space:]]+\!+.+$ ]]; then
  res1="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
  res2="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
  res3="${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
  res1=$(echo $res1 | awk '{ printf "%.6E",$1*1.75 }')
  res3=$(echo $res3 | awk '{ printf "%.6E",$1*1.75 }')
fi
if [[ -n "$r" ]] && [[ -n "$res1" ]] && [[ -n "$res2" ]] && [[ -n "$res3" ]]; then
  echo -e "$r\t\t+$res1\t\t$res2\t\t+$res3"
  r=""
  res1=""
  res2=""
  res3=""
fi
done < <(grep -E "^r[0-9]+f:|^\+[0-9]+\." /path/to/yourfiles)
```

As you can see, there is a awk part there which simply multiply your 1st and 3rd value by 1.75. You can then adjust that as you want.

result:

```
:/tmp$ bash script 
r1f:O2+2PD=>2O-PD       +1.225000E-01       +0.000000E00        +0.000000E+00
r2f:C3H6+2PD=>C3H6-PD       +1.715000E+00       +0.000000E00        +0.000000E+00
r3f:C3H6+O-PD+PD=>C3H5-PD+OH-PD     +4.807808E-01       +0.000000E00        +0.000000E+00
r4f:H2+2PD=>2H-PD       +8.050000E-02       +0.000000E00        +0.000000E+00
r5f:H2O+PD=>H2O-PD      +4.361791E-01       +0.000000E00        +0.000000E+00
r6f:CO2+PD=>CO2-PD      +8.750000E-03       +0.000000E00        +0.000000E+00
```

Comment: Is it possible to generate a variable (say Reaction_rates) and file where only reaction rates are stored?

Comment: in my script, the "r" variable contains your reaction number and the "res" variable contains the rate. Do you want to extract that in 2 separate files?

Comment: Thanks, I got this. It worked well. 
Actually I wanted to change the first value and last value of the reaction rates by a factor +/-75% for each reactions so that I can have 24 new files (each reaction rate changes attributes to 4 new files) like the original InputredKinmech.txt. 
So InputredKinmech01.txt contains changed reaction rates for r1f. 
InputredKinmech02.txt contains changed reaction rates for r2f.
InputredKinmech03.txt contains changed reaction rates for r3f.
and so on...
I know this is not in the Question, but this would be a great help for me.

Comment: I edited my code, don't know if it's okay for you ?

Comment: That's great. Thanks. But I wanted the change in my main file (That I attached).

Comment: I don't understand what you need. Directly edit the original file to keep only the lines you want?

Comment: I am sorry. I edited my Question.